# PyQt5: QTableWidget rezizing with parent window

Tags: pyqt, python-3.4, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am a beginner in using PyQt5. I want to create a dialog with a tableWidget at the window bottom with the same width as window width and allway at bottom If I resize the window, I want to resize the tableWidget too. How can I do this?

Thanks! Geosucher

Comment: Ok, I solved:
For MainWindow I used
`def resizeEvent(self, event):
        w = self.frameGeometry().width()
        h = self.frameGeometry().height()
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, 290, w-10, h-290))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use Qlayouts like this:

```
class myDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.tableWidget=QTableWidget()
        l=QVBoxLayout()
        l.addSpacing(290)
        l.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        l.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(l)
```